# How to program the EDIT and DELETE features in Model Form Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the Models with fields. basically i want to do the CRUD opertions like in admin.I have used

```
Class Meta
      model = Modelname
```

Now my create part is done by defining function create_from.

I want to know that do i need to create separate functions to EDIT , DELETE , READ all Model data. Or i can use buildin admin functions for that. because all the functionality is already on admin side.

Comment: What's your `Meta` class for? Why do you not just use the admin? Are you trying to edit/delete fields from your model programmatically or in a view?

Comment: i had the Article Model and then Articleform and there i used Meta to get all fields from Model. As i am doing all stuff from front end so , i can't use admin. I am doing from a view

Comment: That Meta seems to just be a totally random snippet. Why did you post it?

Comment: My main reason for posting meta was to signify that i used fields auto generated by django for form generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/ - especially the Editing Mixins on that page.

Comment: sorry but i didn't understood anything on that page. i think by that time i should have created my own edit function